# Predicate in conjunction with a map in java8

Tags: java, java-8

Is there an easier/more succinct way than the below to use a predicate within a map with Java8?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add(1);
        test.add(2);
        test.add(3);
        test.add(4);

        List<Integer> test2 = test.stream()
            .map(i -> { if (i % 2 == 0) return i; else return 0;})
            .collect(toList());

        for (int i = 0; i < test2.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(test2.get(i));
        }
    }

Output:
0
2
0
4
```

Essentially, I want to only transform members of my test list if they are odd.

Comment: You're not transforming anything.

Comment: I am making all odd numbers in my test list 0, thats a "transform" of sorts right?

Comment: I guess. But you said you're transforming the even numbers.

Comment: One obvious improvement is to use a ternary expression: `i -> i % 2 == 0 ? i : 0`

Comment: And if you don't mind replacing the list in place (and that the underlying implementation allows to): `test.replaceAll(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? i : 0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Succinct version of your code:

```
List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));

List<Integer> test2 = test.stream()
                          .map(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? i : 0)
                          .collect(toList());
test2.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I don't think you need to get the stream of the a list to use the forEach method. test2.forEach(System.out::println); should work.

Answer (score 1):

This one?

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4).map(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? i : 0).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or if you want *only* even numbers in the stream (e.g. starting from 2) why not this one?

```
IntStream.iterate(2, i -> i + 2).limit(2).forEach(System.out::println);
```